# send request with gwt to a different domain

Tags: gwt

Is there a way I can make a request to a different server than the one that's being used for development using a RequestBuilder?

I keep getting

```
com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestPermissionException: The URL
http://127.0.0.1:4321/getSellers is invalid or violates the same-origin
security restriction
```

while I am sending request from 127.0.0.1:8888

Answer (score 1):

GWT currently doesnt support cross domain ajax calls - but it can be worked around if you are willing to do a bit of jsni. And I heard a rumour some time ago that there is a gwt patch with the solution, but its not perfect. see this http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit-Contributors/browse_thread/thread/94c18c4ec158070c/

to work around using jsni, you can use whats called the windows.name transport - see this blog http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/ . i havent been able to locate a library for gwt to automate this, but i dont think its too hard to do yourself in jsni (and dont me misled by the blog being about dojo, its a general technique).

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed explanation on the topic of the Same Origin Policy and its consequences for developing with GWT here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_SOP

The simple answer is: No, that's something that is disallowed for security reasons.
However, it should be possible to work around this limitation with all kinds of techniques (proxy servers, [Yahoo Pipes](http://www.badlydrawntoy.com/2008/07/08/yahoo-pipes-and-jquery-same-origin-policy/), etc). As I'm no AJAX expert, I will leave the explanation of those to others.